# SQL Server, get record which having both skills

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I have a employee table and a skill table.

In skills table, I have entries like

```
empid    skills
---------------
 1       C#
 1       PHP
 2       C#
 2       Java
```

Now I want all employee id's which have both C# and Java.

Comment: You should post your query attempt, even if it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option aggregates by employees and asserts that both C# and Java are present as skills.

```
SELECT empid
FROM employee
WHERE skills IN ('C#', 'Java')
GROUP BY empid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skills) = 2;
```

### Demo